# Is there a better, cleaner way to write this Yup schema validator (used by React Formik component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I only want to call the service endpoint (db.checkEmail) if the email value is an email formatted string.

```
    const yupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
            .email()
            .required('Required')
            .test('alreadyUsed', 'Not Available', async (value) => {
                const result = await Yup.string()
                    .email()
                    .required('Required')
                    .validate(value)
                    .then((email) => db.checkEmail({email}));

                return result.data.count === 0;

            })
        ,
        password: Yup.string()
            .required('Required')
    })
```

It seems that checking the string twice is redundant... but if I leave the validate out then all three validations run.

I am using the documentation found here:
[Yup github README.md](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestoptions-object-schema)

under the mixed.test section it says:

> In order to allow asynchronous custom validations all (or no) tests are run asynchronously. A consequence of this is that test execution order cannot be guaranteed.

So I am trying to guarantee that I don't make an expensive api call unless I really need to...

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the solution above and it seems to work fine and do what I want it to do.

```
    const yupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
            .email()
            .required('Required')
            .test('alreadyUsed', 'Not Available', (value) => Yup.string()
                    .email()
                    .required('Required')
                    .validate(value)
                    .then((email) => db.checkEmail({email}))
                    .then(({data:{count}}) => count === 0)),
        password: Yup.string()
            .required('Required')
    });
```